# Read and write file from SD card with FPGA

Tags: fpga, sd

I'm working on a simple project with Quartus in which I've tried to implementent a NIOS II processor to read from, and write to, an SD Card.

Here it is the schematic:

[image]

The C code is:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <system.h>
#include <altera_up_sd_card_avalon_interface.h>

short int sd_fileh, sd_fileh2, att;
char buffer[512]="WELCOME TO THE INTERFACE!!\r\n\0";
char data[512];
int i, pixel, att3;

int main()
{
  printf("SD Card Access Test\n");
  alt_up_sd_card_dev *sd_card_dev = ("/dev/Altera_UP_SD_Card_Avalon_Interface_0");

  if (sd_card_dev != 0) // Checking if the card is present
  {
    if (alt_up_sd_card_is_Present())
    {
      if (alt_up_sd_card_is_FAT16()) // Checking if is FAT16
        printf("Card is FAT16\n");
      else
        printf("Card is not FAT16\n");

      sd_fileh = alt_up_sd_card_fopen("test1.txt", true); // Creating a new text file and writing data on it

      if (sd_fileh < 0)
        printf("Problem creating file. Error%i", sd_fileh);
      else
      {
        printf("SD Accessed Successufully, writing data...\n");
        int index = 0;

        while (buffer[index] != '\0') // Write the data in the buffer to the file
        {
          alt_up_sd_card_write(sd_fileh, buffer[index]);
          index = index + 1;
        }

        printf("Writing done!\n");
        printf("Closing file 1...\n");
        alt_up_sd_card_fclose(sd_fileh);
      }

      // *****reading text file***********
      sd_fileh2 = alt_up_sd_card_fopen("test2.txt", false);

      if (sd_fileh2 < 0)
        printf("Problem creating file. Error %i", sd_fileh2);
      else
      {
        printf("SD Accessed successfully, reading data...\n");
        printf("Data read fromthe text file = \n");
        for (i=0; i<12; i++)
        {
          data[i]= alt_up_sd_card_read(sd_fileh);
          printf("%c",data[i]);
        }

        printf("\Closing file...");
        alt_up_sd_card_fclose(sd_fileh2);
        printf("Done\n");
      }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

With the Altera monitor program I start the program, but it stops at the first `printf`. What is wrong?

Comment: Is this C code running on the processor you've put inside the FPGA? Why are you sure the softcore in the FPGA is working as you expected?

Comment: Yes, that is the code. About the softcore I'm not really sure if it works as I expected, because I have doubts that the sd's pins are configurated correctly, but che compilation process is done successfully. So I don't 'know why the code prints the first printf and then doesn't do anything else.

Comment: I don't see your code doing anything if an SD card is not present. Put an else statement that indicates that a card is not present. You need to see if you can actually detect the card first before you do anything else.

Comment: As David has asked about what happens if there is no card, how are you testing this? Have you got an FPGA test bench running, or is this running in real life?

Comment: I've added at the end else { printf("card not present")} and on the console is printed that. I suspect that I've done something wrong with the nios because it seems that the sd card port is not configurated correctly

Comment: Now that you've confirmed you are not detecting the card, you need to find out why. Is the firmware module "nios_sd_card" IP or is it something you wrote yourself? (I hope it's the former) Also, how does the processor connect to that firmware module?

Answer (score 0):

From page 8 of [Altera University Program Secure Data Card IP Core](ftp://ftp.intel.com/Pub/fpgaup/pub/Intel_Material/15.1/University_Program_IP_Cores/Memory/SD_Card_Interface_for_SoPC_Builder.pdf) and modified for your string, you could try:

```c
alt_up_sd_card_dev *sd_card_dev = alt_up_sd_card_open_dev("/dev/Altera_UP_SD_Card_Avalon_Interface_0");
```

Comment: I've tried but is not working. And I Also have a problem with the altera monitor program: for few times, I have the following error: Using cable "USB-Blaster [USB-0]", device 1, instance 0x00 Pausing target processor: not responding. Resetting and trying again: FAILED 
Leaving target processor paused